# response data is defined but data.value is undefined?

Tags: angularjs

Below data coupon is ng-model. i send the ng-model to api and i got the response.in side the get total response defined. out side get data.value undefined

and i use the response in list object like dataresult.offerprice

```
mainCtrl.controller("MainController",function(,$scope,$rootScope,$q)
$scope.ResultInfo=function(){

var couponres=$resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/promocode?code="+$scope.coupon.offer)

  return couponres.get(function(data){
        console.log(data);
     $rootScope.coupon=data;   
        return data;
    });
       }
       dataresult=$scope.ResultInfo();
       console.log(dataresult);
         console.log(dataresult.offerprice);

$scope.list={"hascoupan","coupanvalue":dataresult.offerprice ,"coupanamt":dataresult.offerprice,"ordertotal": $scope.Total()};
```

dataresult:Response

```
Resource {offerid: "6", offerprice: "30", $promise: Promise, $resolved: true}
$promise: Promise$resolved: trueofferid: "6"offerprice: "30"
__proto__: Object2

dataresult.offerprice:Response

undefined
```

please tell me how get the data outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the response after you receive it, which is - inside the success callback:

```js
return couponres.get(function(data) {

  // Do whatever you want with the data here

  console.log(data);
  $scope.list = {
    "hascoupan": true, // <-- some value should be here
    "coupanvalue": data.offerprice,
    "coupanamt": data.offerprice,
    "ordertotal": $scope.Total()
  };
  return data;
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Suggestion. it is working for my project@ T J